# Передать XML методом POST на сервер доставки СДЭК

Tags: php, xml, post

Необходимо передать данные с интернет магазина на сервер доставки СДЭК с помощью XML.
Скрипт просто перестают грузить страницу дальше. 
В чём может быть причины ? :(

```
<?php
$soap = curl_init("https://integration.cdek.ru/new_orders.php");
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//Создаём уникальный хэш
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date = date('c');
$secure = md5($date.'&'.c22236e1ed7ed9e22cba9e811f963bec);

$request = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<DeliveryRequest Number="236" Date="2016-09-25T12:45:10" Account="f90461d1db11f060474b9cd4aa1b91f0" Secure="<?=$secure?>" 
OrderCount="1">
<Order Number="1010203040"  
DeliveryRecipientCost="0"   
SendCityCode="270"      
RecCityCode="44"    
RecipientName="Тест"    
Phone="7810999, 9295849151"     
Comment="Тест"  TariffTypeCode="5"  RecientCurrency="RUB"   
ItemsCurrency="RUB">    
<Address PvzCode="MSK2" />  
<Package Number="1" BarCode="101" Weight="630">        
<Item 
WareKey="25000050368" 
Cost="49" 
Payment="49" 
Weight="68" 
Amount="1" 
Comment="Тест"/>       
<Item WareKey="25000348563" 
Cost="79" 
Payment="79"
Weight="95" 
Amount="1" 
Comment="вы"/>      
</Package>  
<AddService ServiceCode="30"></AddService>   
</Order> 
</DeliveryRequest>
XML;

curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
        array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 
              'Content-Length: '.strlen($request)));

curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
$response = curl_exec($soap);
print_r ($response);
curl_close($soap);
?>
```

Comment: Какие ошибки выдаёт?

Comment: У Вас в строке где `$secure = md5($date.'&'.c22236e3ed7ed9e22cba9e851f963bec);` не понятно что такое  c22236e3ed7ed9e22cba9e851f963bec вы бы хоть в кавычки завернули бы

Comment: Это ключ который нужно по этой формуле шифровать. Кавычки помогли.
Но почему-то выдаёт ошибку http://prntscr.com/gkjmeu

Comment: Там же всё написано. У Вас в коде должно передаваться постом xml_request. Необходимо поискать $_POST['xml_request'] где вы его получаете и почему он не передаётся

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно передавать данные в параметре `xml_request`. Например, так:

```
$soap = curl_init('https://integration.cdek.ru/new_orders.php');
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$request = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<DeliveryRequest />
XML;

curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'xml_request' => $request
]);

$response = curl_exec($soap);

var_dump($response);

curl_close($soap);
```

Если передавать не в параметре, или назвать его как-то не так, то API прямо так и скажет в сообщении об ошибке:

```
<response ErrorCode="ERR_XML_EMPTY" Msg="Значение переменной $_POST[xml_request] пустое" />
```

Вообще же самому разводить зоопарк из cURL и писать руками XML - это дело гиблое и, вообще, никому не нужное. Берёте готовую [библиотеку для работы с API СДЭК](https://github.com/sanmai/cdek-sdk), и вот вы уже посылаете новые заказы, печатаете этикетки, и так далее.

Full disclosure: автор этого ответа и есть автор [той библиотеки](https://github.com/sanmai/cdek-sdk).

Comment: Уважаемый **sanmai**. Ваш вариант с **xml_request** полностью работоспособен - за это огромное СПАСИБО - заказы отсылаются в CDEK. Но остались вопросы на которые я сам из-за отсутствия должного опыта не смог найти ответ. Суть вот в чём. После отправки данных, в ответе сервера, "на поверхности", отображается только значение TraceId в виде условного набора знаков. Но если посмотреть на исходный код страницы ответа, - он содержит нужную информацию в формате XML, - трек-номер, внутренний номер заказа и т.д.:
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><response><Order DispatchNumber

Comment: @alex_tm пользуйтесь [готовой библиотекой](https://cdek-sdk.readthedocs.io/), там все эти вопросы уже решены за вас!

Comment: sanmai, как с вами связаться по поводу этой библиотеки для СДЭК? Вопрос простой, но тут не место для него.

Comment: Через наш чат в телеграме можно попробовать задать вопрос, иначе в данных на GitHub есть необходимая контактная информация